# How do I replace data of some range of std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, containers

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.push_back('a');
v.push_back('b');
v.push_back('c');
v.push_back('d');
v.push_back('e');
v.push_back('f');

char c[3] = { 'z', 'x', 'y' };

// Want to make abzxyf
//v.insert(v.begin() + 2, c, c + 3); // it doesn't work as I wanted.

// Yes it works. but if c is more bigger, it will be crash.
std::copy(c, c + 3, v.begin() + 2);

v.clear();
v.push_back('a');
v.push_back('b');
v.push_back('c');
v.push_back('d');
v.push_back('e');
v.push_back('f');

// If vector needs more memory, I'd let him grow automactically
// So I tried this.(expected abcdezxy)
// But it's result is abcdezxyf. f is still remain.
std::copy(c, c + 3, std::inserter(v, v.begin() + 5));
```

What algorithm or method should I use?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Do you want to insert elements or overwrite elements?

Comment: I guess "replace data" would imply overwrite.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to archive, but maybe `replace` or `replace_if` from the STL Algorithms will do what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the `sizeof(c)` is bigger, `resize()` before the `copy()` that should do the trick.

e.g.

```
if (sizeof(c) + 2 > v.size())
  v.resize(sizeof(c) + 2);
// now copy
std::copy(c, c + sizeof(c), v.begin() + 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do text processing, you might consider using `std::string` which has `replace` functions.

`std::vector` does not. You have to use the appropriate combination of overwriting members combined with `insert` and `erase`.